# nextUntil hasClass jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextuntil

Here's my code
[image]

I want to toggle closest class `'.wdm_bundled_item'` on `'.mainClass_`n`'`

What I had tried :

```
jQuery('.mainClass_1').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nextUntil('.codeByBilal').toggle();
    });
```

Working fine, just the issue is it's toggling the last `tr` too when I click on `'.mainClass_4'`

Any suggestion please? with `nextUntil` or something else.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give your last row another class and do `.nextUntil('.codeByBilal,.otherClass')` ?  Alternatively, it's possible to find where a class is missing, eg `.nextUntil('.codeByBilal,:not(.cart_item)')`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue. Please provide a working fiddle for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter()` to filter out the elements with the desired class.

```
jQuery('.mainClass_1').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).nextUntil('.codeByBilal').filter('.wdm_bundled_item').toggle();
});
```